# PHP script not working on local computer but works on the webserver

Tags: php, mysql, configuration

I am new to coding in php and also getting the environment set up on my local computer.

Here's the current setup configuration - I have installed wamp server version 2.2 which has the following - Apache  2.4.2, php 5.4.3, mysql 5.5.24

There is a very simple php code that i had written -

```
<?
mysql_connect("localhost","user","password");
mysql_select_db("mydbase");
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM names WHERE ID LIKE '2'"); 
   while($r=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
$id = $r["id"];
$name = $r["name"];

}//close while
?>
```

Even a simple echo is not working. the output is blank. the same code works on the web server. It has the same user name, password and the tables were exported (from the webserver) and imported (into the local mysql).

**The phpinfo() page shows the following** -

display_errors - on - on
error_log - no value - no value

**The php.ini file shows the following** -
    ; display_errors
    ; Default Value: On
    ; Development Value: On
    ; Production Value: Off
and

```
;error_log = php_errors.log
; Log errors to syslog (Event Log on NT, not valid in Windows 95).
;error_log = syslog
error_log = c:/wamp/logs/php_error.log
```

**The error logs are empty.**

When i look at the source in the browser, 
for the page online - it shows the output
for the page on the local computer - it just shows the php code

Could anyone please let me know what the problem could be? It seems like that there are some settings that i have messed up. But, i did not change anything - it is a regular installation and no custom settings were added.

Comment: Has the file the `.php` as extension?

Comment: What does <php phpinfo(); ?> show you?

Comment: Make sure that the *server* (I assume apache) is set up to handle php requests.  It should be handling php extensions with `application/x-httpd-php` (and `mod_php` should be enabled unless you are using FastCGI or something)

Comment: Does the MySQL user/password form the webserver also exist on your local server?

Comment: @MikeBrant "It has the same user name, password and the tables were exported (from the webserver) and imported (into the local mysql)"

Comment: @Sven - the file has a .php extension....

Comment: @DainisAbols - how do i check <php phpinfo(); ?> ?

Comment: Are you accessing it via `http://localhost/file.php`, or just opening `file.php` in the browser? In other words, is the web server actually _serving_ it?

Comment: @michael - yes, it is showing the non php content - it is showing the html text. i am accessing it using http://127.0.0.1/file.php

Comment: @nk369 create a file info.php and write `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` in it.

Comment: @DainisAbols - it is showing me the phpinfo() . is there anything specific out of this that i should write - i checked display_errors and error_log which i have pasted above in the question....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script doesn't work, but your phpinfo page works?  Check short_open_tag in your php.ini.  Or modify your script and change your opening `<?` to `<?php`.  If that works, you found the problem!

Comment: the short_open_tag is set to off (on both local and master value)

Comment: Glad to hear it helped, but to please refer from **not** using short opening tags. That's not good practice.

Comment: @DainisAbols, oh, okay.. didnt know that. was just experimenting with a code i found.. will use the standard codes now.. (which i am assuming, would be using <?php > instead of <? > )

Answer (score 0):

this happened to me too, try enabling the mime_module of apache

Comment: the mime_module is enabled (there is a tick next to it in Apache Modules in the WAMP configuration)

Answer (score 0):

If, on info.php file creation with

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

You actully get that result, check if your webserver is configured to use php as script files:

Check inside httpd.conf for these lines and alter them if necessary:

```
<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
</IfModule>
```

Restart server and try to run the script again.

Comment: Or try installing an older wamp version and carefully click on all php options when installing it. That might be easier for you.

Comment: i checked the httpd.conf and it shows the following <IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.php3 index.html index.htm
</IfModule>